# Oracle Free Tier регистрация

Tags: vps

Пытался недавно зарегистрироваться на Oracle Free Tier. Какую-бы карту не использовал, всегда получаю это (картинка не моя, взята с интернета, но суть передаёт ту же):
[image: Ошибка при регистрации]

Карты все дебетовые (VISA momentum), не виртуальные или предоплаченные, покупки с них в интернете делаются спокойно.
Кто-то смог зарегистрироваться? Если да, то чьи имя/фамилию вы вводили и на какой адрес почты регистрировались?

В службу поддержки уже писал. Прошло 48 часов, а ответа все ещё нет :(

Answer (score 0):

Для некоторых видов карт в банке существуют ограничения на "покупки в Интернете". Если это Visa Classic (хотя на картинке виден логотип именно MasterCard), то с большой долей вероятности это ограничение действует. Вам следует уточнить в банке - там либо снимут ограничение (и, как вариант, подключат 3D Security), либо предложат другую карту с другим набором услуг.

Comment: Не, ограничений нет

Comment: Ну а в банке что говорят? Почему отклоняется попытка оплаты?

Comment: Сбербанк сказал, что ограничений на покупки до 100000 рублей нет, может фамилию неправильно пишете (хотя я пишу заглавными буквами как в реквизитах для переводов в долларах). Остальные покупки проходят нормально. А здесь деньги списываются, возвращаются, а карта все равно потом не проходит (тут дело не в оплате, а том, что ораклу почему-то не нравится моя карта)